# Почему на айпаде отображается бордер хотя он не задан?

Tags: html, css, frontend, border

На десктопе бордер не виден, но на айпаде прям очень сильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cloud {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cloud_big {
  width: 30rem;
  font-size: 7.2rem;
  border-radius: 3.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.2rem;
}

.green_cloud {
  background-color: #25B553;
  border-color: #25B553;
  color: #fff;
}

.cloud:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 3.9rem;
  height: 4.4rem;
  right: -2.9rem;
  bottom: -0.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
  transform: rotate(65deg);
  border-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 1.5rem solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud cloud_big green_cloud">
Облако
</div>
```

Comment: масштаб 100%? или меньше?

Comment: @meine при чем тут масштаб? эта проблема только айпада. Картинку я увеличил максимально, чтобы было видно. На компе и на айфоне этого нет

Comment: смотрю с айпада и все нормально

Comment: @meine у меня iPad Air, мб плотность пикселей решает. Хотя хер знает